# How do I make a text input non-editable for a part of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a text input

```
<input type="text" value="+98912314789" class="telinfo">
```

Is there a way to keep 4 letter from the begin ?
I want to keep `+9891` read only and the user can delete all part of this textbox except this part.

Comment: you can use input mask

Comment: why put them in the input element in the first place? An editable entity is editable, while non-editable are not. There is a design to this.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I want to send it with form . span does not work to me

Comment: try using digitalbush

Comment: @guradio  How can I use this ?

Comment: @31piy I want to send it with form . span does not work to me

Comment: Your answer is here : https://jsfiddle.net/so9rbgnh/1/

Comment: [check here](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) for more details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can capture the `keyup` and `blur` (in case user directly copy paste the value in textbox) event

```
function handleEv( event )
{
   var thisObj = event.currentTarget;
   var fixedValue = thisObj.getAttribute( "data-fixedvalue" );
   if ( thisObj.value.indexOf( fixedValue )  != 0 )
   {
      console.log(thisObj.value, fixedValue);
      event.preventDefault();
      thisObj.value = fixedValue;
   }
}
```

**Demo of sample implementation**

```js
var el = document.querySelector( ".telinfo" );
el.addEventListener( "keyup", handleEv);
el.addEventListener( "blur", handleEv);


function handleEv( event )
{
   var thisObj = event.currentTarget;
   var fixedValue = thisObj.getAttribute( "data-fixedvalue" );
   if ( thisObj.value.indexOf( fixedValue )  != 0 )
   {
      console.log(thisObj.value, fixedValue);
      event.preventDefault();
      thisObj.value = fixedValue;
   }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="+98912314789" class="telinfo" data-fixedvalue = "+9891">
```

Comment: Thanks. If I have another input with another constant value like +78 will I use this js code again?

Comment: @inaz Code is fairly generic, it takes the value from an attribute of the textbox `data-fixedvalue`... you just need to set that attribute and invoke this event handler on that element.

Comment: I invoke another input like this. var el = document.querySelector( ".telinfo, .mobinfo" ); but does not work to me

Comment: `querySelector` returns **single element**, use `querySelectorAll` and **iterate** the element list to bind the event.

Comment: var el = document.querySelectorAll( ".telinfo, .mobinfo" ); I've added querySelectorAll but  my code doesn't work at all. how can I iterate this?

Comment: is there another task to do ?

Answer (score 1):

try this code may be it will help to resolve your issue

```
<input type="text" value="+98912314789" class="telinfo" id="telphone" onchange="staticData()" onkeyup="staticData()">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function staticData(){
  var data=$("#telphone");
  if(data.val().length<5)
    {
     data.val("+9891");
     data.attr("readonly",true);
    }
    else
    {
     data.attr("readonly",false);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This question solved by `@gurvinder372` but you could achieve this easier than it with `Regex` pattern:

```js
function phoneNumber(selector, num) {
  $(selector).on('input', function() {
    var reg = /\+/gi;
    if (!$(this).val().match(reg)) {
      $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/([\d]+)/g, "+" + num + "$1"));
    }
  });
}


phoneNumber('.telinfo', '9891');
phoneNumber('.mobinfo', '78');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="+9891" class="telinfo">
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="+78" class="mobinfo">
```

**Update:** Also I converted this to function to usable multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Try using two inputs one for readonly and second for editing -

```
<input type="text" value="+9891" readonly>
<input type="text" value="" class="telinfo">
```

Wrap it in a container to add both inputs on the same line.

Comment: Or just put the non-editable part in a `<span>` tag

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is separating the read-only text from input text

```
<input type="text" value="+9891" size="3" disabled>
<input type="text" value="">
```

Comment: i want a form with a input I need this value for sending to other page with form . in this way that you mentioned i cannot have all of value with a name

Answer (score 0):

make css and html like below change style as per your requirement

```
<div class="field">
   <input type="text" value="" class="telinfo">
</div>
.field{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 240px;
   }
     .field:before{
      content: "+9891";
      position: absolute;
      left: 15px;
      top: 10px

     }
   .field input{
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid  #ddd;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 58px; 
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #000;
   }
```

Comment: I need this value for my form . I need to have the first part of it all the time. CSS does not work to me